# how to link my two php image uploading scripts

Tags: php, image, gd

I am actually uploading an image from my computer through php and I am also then creating a transparent image which I actually want to merge with my uploaded image.
I have got a function for merging my both images(imagecopymerge) but the problem is my all the three scripts are working independently and I am not able to link my all the three scripts(image uploading, image creating and merging both images) and unable to produce any result.

can u please suggest me ways to link my all the three scripts.??

1. script for uploading any image from my system.

   ```
   <?php
   $target_dir = "uploads/";
   $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
   $uploadOk = 1;
   $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
   if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
     $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
     if($check !== false) {
         echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
        $uploadOk = 1;
       } else {
             echo "File is not an image.";
             $uploadOk = 0;
              }

   }

   header("Location: http://localhost/image_editor/test.php?file=$target_file");
   ?>
   <?php
   //Set the Content Type
   header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
   #dispaly the image
   $file=$_GET['file'];
   echo file_get_contents($file);
   ?>
   ```
2. creating an image with transparent background.

   ```
   <?php

   //set the content type
   header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

   //create the image
   $im = imagecreatetruecolor(250, 200);
   $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
   $blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);

   // Make the background transparent
   imagecolortransparent($im, $black);

   //text to draw
   $text=$_POST['text'];
   //font path
   $font = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid/DroidSans.ttf';
   // Add the text
   imagettftext($im, 15, 0, 50, 50, $blue, $font, $text);

   //view the image
   imagejpeg($im);
   imagedestroy($im);
   ?>
   ```
3. merging both images.

   ```
   <?php

   //create image instances
   $dest=imagecreatefromjpeg($target_file);
   $src=imagecreatefromjpeg($im);

   // Copy and merge
   imagecopymerge();

   // Output and free from memory
   header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
   imagejpeg($dest);

   imagedestroy($dest);
   imagedestroy($src);
   ?>
   ```

Comment: What are you do it? Why you want to use 3 scripts? Why not one? I don't understand. Please, explain :)

Comment: Post your all 3 scripts. I will try to help you.

Comment: How about pull all 3 scripts in the same file...?

Comment: When I am bringing all the scripts in the same file, Its displaying error. I think I am not ablt to do that in proper manner.